# B2B application, checkbox is not visible

Tags: ios, objective-c, checkbox, app-store-connect, b2b

I'm creating a B2B application. I have seen that I need to click on the checkbox "B2B custom app" in the pricing section in itunes connect. I have a valid Paid application contract.
The problem is : when I click on pricing for one of my public app already on the app store, I don't see the checkbox "B2B custom app".

My question is, is this normal that I don't see the checkbox "B2B custom app" for my applications that are already on the store (because they are already publics so they can't be B2B), and I will see this checkbox when I will create my B2B app on itunes connect, or is it another problem ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find an answer in Apple documentation. But I have checked a few apps in my iTunesConnect account and it's obvious that you can see the checkbox "B2B custom app" only for the first version of your app before you send it to review.

Also maybe [this article](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/B2B.html) that describes the Custom B2B App option will be useful.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Victor, must be for the first version.